# In React Native how to respond incoming call with recorded voice

Tags: android, react-native

I'm developing an application and I want to respond the incoming call with pre-recorded voice.

I have searched on Stack Overflow and found this answer [1]. I have also found this source from developer site [2].

Does we can play the audio file for incoming calls?

Is this a good approach to bind native code with react-native to respond incoming call as mentioned in this [1] example?

[1] [Android: Incoming call auto answer, play a audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929489/android-incoming-call-auto-answer-play-a-audio-file)

[2] https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged